# OneNote Api - notebooks endpoint returns 403 for account owner

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

The API is returning a 403 (Forbidden) error when making a call from our iOS app with a work/business account to `https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/notebooks`

The account being used is the administrator, the access token was properly generated using the ADAL library, the two-factor authentication is turned off and the app has the proper access in app permissions.

Is there any other reason for this error to happen?

Any pointers/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 typically happens when your app did not request the right permissions to get resources on our API.

If this is a new integration, I would encourage you to use the Microsoft Graph API. It has generally more recently updated code samples, and almost all the functionality of the OneNote API is already in MS Graph.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/ios
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

If you give us the value of the X-CorrelationId in the response of your 403, we can help you look into this.

---

EDIT

Looked at your logs - this isn't the case. You have the right scopes. However, you are running into the problem below (take a look at your response payload and you will see an error code returned)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2016/09/11/onenote-api-calls-fail-with-a-large-number-of-items-in-a-sharepoint-document-library/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The X-CorrelationId is 621bfd63-d35d-4688-9390-f4502d5c079e

Comment: Apologize - can you provide the X-CorrelationId, and the timestamp specified (also in a header) by the response?

Comment: This is the timestamp and x-CorrelationId `Date = "Fri, 29 Sep 2017 17:13:49 GMT"; "X-CorrelationId" = "621bfd63-d35d-4688-9390-f4502d5c079e";`

Comment: Responded above (In case you had not seen it)